# Can we remove the Duplicate rows in table using the Any Join?

Tags: java, sql, oracle11g

Suppose

T1:

```
Col1 Col2
---- ----
   1 a
   1 b
   2 c
   3 d
```

T2:

```
Col1 Col2
---- ----
   1 b
   2 c
   3 d
```

What is Exact query of this, to remove the duplicate rows using Join.

Comment: What do you believe is a duplicate row in your example ?

Comment: There isn't enough information here - are you trying to remove rows from T1 that are present in T2?

Comment: Please show us the result that you expect.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from T1
MINUS
select * from T2
```

This will only get you the rows of T1 which are not in T2.

Comment: Thanks, but can we do same using the join in oracle

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
delete from t1 a where not exists(select * from t2 b where a.col1=b.col1 and a.col2=b.col2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the rows of `T1` that don't exist in `T2` with a join then use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select T1.*
from T1 left join T2
on T2.col1 = T1.col1 and T2.col2 = T1.col2
where T2.col1 is null
```

If you want the rows that are not common in the 2 tables you can do it with a `FULL OUTER JOIN`:

```
select
  coalesce(T1.col1, T2.col1) col1,
  coalesce(T1.col2, T2.col2) col2
from T1 full outer join T2
on T2.col1 = T1.col1 and T2.col2 = T1.col2
where T1.col1 is null or T2.col1 is null
```

The condition in the `WHERE` clause makes sure that only rows that belong to one and not the other of the tables will be returned.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4662e9dff9862d7a10e350f71a243198).
Results:

```
> COL1 | COL2
> ---: | :---
>    1 | a
```

Comment: @NaveenArora `T1.col1 is not null` would return duplicates also. Check the demo in my answer.